# Bound MySQL query time and bail with partial result

Tags: php, mysql

I am searching for a way to be sure a SELECT query returns within a given maximum time, returning with partial results if necessary.

Here is the more detailed issue that I am facing:

I have a quite a lot of tables looking like this:

```
table name: user_1

date       | object_id  | row_id
2015-05-13 | 0          | 1
2015-05-13 | 0          | 2
2015-05-14 | 0          | 3
...
2015-06-15 | 0          | 5000001
2015-06-15 | 0          | 5000002
2015-06-15 | 0          | 5000003
2015-06-16 | 123        | 5000004
2015-06-17 | 435        | 5000005
```

I have similar tables for `user_1` to `user_1000`.

There is a PRIMARY INDEX on `row_id` and an INDEX on `date`.

We are in the middle of a migration process. All new data (after 2015-06-16) are created with a non-zero `object_id` and past data can be or cannot be migrated. A table is migrated if any of the row before 2015-06-16 has a non-zero `object_id` field.

I try to know if a table's data are migrated with the following request:

```
SELECT * FROM user_1 WHERE date < 2015-06-16 AND object_id > 0 LIMIT 1
```

It works as expected. It's fast when the data are migrated (the engine find quickly a row matching the WHERE clause). It's slow when data are not migrated (the engine parse all rows to be sure nothing matches the WHERE clause). There is no index on the `object_id` column and I cannot create one.

To quicken things I tried to read only the first row:

```
SELECT object_id FROM user_1 ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1
```

I test `object_id > 0` in my PHP code. It's always quick and that's great. But I can have false negative results because the migration process sometimes cannot migrate a row, in which case `object_id` is still 0.

My third attempt is to search in a given time-range, to decrease the probability of false-positive.

```
SELECT * FROM user_1 WHERE object_id > 0 AND date BETWEEN 2015-06-01 AND 2015-06-15 LIMIT 1
```

The thing is I am not sure I have rows between these dates for all `user_*` tables. It's possible there is no row in this date range while the table is still migrated. If I set a large date range, the query is slower.

So, back to my question, I'd like to do a request that searches for rows matching my WHERE clause for at most let's say 100ms. If it finds a migrated row in 3ms, the query returns quickly, otherwise I reduce the false-negative case but I only spend only 100ms in that attempt.

I know I can set a timeout with MySQL 5.7, but I'm stuck with MySQL 5.5. Table engine is TokuDB. There is also PHP 5.5 with PDO. A solution similar to [ElasticSearch's timeout](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html) would be perfect.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to control the execution time of my request by performing a sub-request. I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but I can indirectly infer the execution time by modifying the inner `LIMIT` value.

Setting `LIMIT 10000` is faster than `LIMIT 100000` but 100000 reduce false-negative cases.

The old request:

```
SELECT * FROM user_1 WHERE date < 2015-06-16 AND object_id > 0 LIMIT 1
```

becomes

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT object_id FROM user_1
    WHERE date < 2015-06-16
    LIMIT 100000
) s
WHERE s.object_id > 0
LIMIT 1
```